# loaded UICollectionviewCell reload every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have only one cell for showing the post in collection view like Instagram. I'm showing data of single post but it reload every time when slightly change the content offset of collection view. For example I am playing the video in collection view but when it scroll element of cell again added and video play from start again.

Please reply me. Thanks.

```
UICollectionViewCell cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
if (cell != nil) {
 for (UIView view in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
  { 
    [view removeFromSuperview];
  }
} 
return cell;
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if (cell != nil)
    {
        for (UIView* view in [cell.contentView subviews])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
  

return cell;